# Computing the shadow of a complex MultiPolygon Z in the (x,y) plane

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, shadow

I have a 3D feature (for example a complex building) given as an ESRI Shape file which I'm loading in Python as a [GeodataFrame](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html):

[image]

This is a MultiPolygon Z. It is definitely *not* a valid geometry because it contains several "vertical planes", i.e. some vertices are at the same (x,y) position but have different z values:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("the_building.shp")

gdf.iloc[0].geometry.geom_type
>: 'MultiPolygon'

gdf.iloc[0].geometry.has_z
>: True

gdf.iloc[0].geometry.is_valid
>: False
```

I would like to extract the external border as a 2D (multi)polygon:

[image]

To this end I was thinking of "simply" *drawing* its shadow (polygon) on the (x,y) plane, as cast by a light source considered to be infinitely far away from above.

Splitting the MultiPolygon Z to its single parts, removing their z values and dissolving them all together is not considered a valid option because it actually gives strange/invalid results, e.g. a `POLYGON EMPTY` geometry. This is certainly because removing the z values of a vertical plane is basically giving a polygon which is a "line" having duplicate nodes (the ones with same (x,y) vertices but different z in the original 3D shape), e.g.:

```
polygon_list = list(gdf.iloc[0].geometry)

polygon_list[1].geom_type
>: 'Polygon'

polygon_list[1].is_valid
>: False

polygon_list[1].exterior.xy
>: 
(array('d', [94128.9893000014, 94741.088399999, 94741.088399999, 94128.9893000014, 2494148.9893000014]),
 array('d', [20878.4521999992, 20830.6237999983, 20830.6237999983, 20878.4521999992, 20848.4521999992]))
```

Do you know a way to solve this problem within Python (3.9+)?

For the moment I'm trying to build a Delaunay triangulation but then I cannot remove the external triangles by computing "*whatever spatial predicate*" with the input geometry because of its invalidity.

[image]